# magento 1.6 importing product .csv file, result with no image displayed

Tags: magento, csv, import, magento-1.6

I am importing magento 1.3 product to magento 1.6. I have changed all the columns so that it will be fine in magento 1.6. I have done in the importing with 8000 products in magento 1.6 and I have put all the images in the 'media/import' (I have also set the permission to 777).

When I look to the 'catalog manage product' and look for the images, there are none. I also looked in the database at the 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery' table but it is empty.

Can anyone help me with my case?

this is my .csv header first.

```
_store
_product_websites
_attribute_set
_type
sku
_category
has_options
price
cost
name
image
small_image
url_key
thumbnail
url_path
image_label
small_image_label
thumbnail_label
description
short_description
internal_notes
productinfo
enable_googlecheckout
visibility
tax_class_id
status
qty
min_qty
use_config_min_qty
is_qty_decimal
backorders
use_config_backorders
min_sale_qty
use_config_min_sale_qty
max_sale_qty
use_config_max_sale_qty
is_in_stock
notify_stock_qty
use_config_notify_stock_qty
manage_stock
use_config_manage_stock
stock_status_changed_auto
serial_number
manufacturer2
qty_loc1
qty_loc2
qty_loc3
loc1
loc2
special_price
special_from_date
special_to_date
loc3
weight
meta_title
meta_description
gift_message_available
custom_design
options_container
page_layout
meta_keyword
in_depth
dimension
hardrive
memory
custom_layout_update
computer_manufacturers
color
manufacturer
news_from_date
news_to_date
```

then I try this one.

```
sku
_store
_attribute_set
_type
_category
_product_websites
activation_information
bss_weight
color
computer_manufacturers
contrast_ratio
cost
country_of_manufacture
cpu_speed
created_at
custom_design
custom_design_from
custom_design_to
custom_layout_update
description
dimension
enable_googlecheckout
finish
gallery
gender
gift_message_available
harddrive_speed
hardrive
has_options
image
image_label
internal_notes
in_depth
loc1
loc2
loc3
location1
location2
location3
manufacturer
manufacturer2
max_resolution
media_gallery
meta_description
meta_keyword
meta_title
minimal_price
msrp
msrp_display_actual_price_type
msrp_enabled
name
news_from_date
news_to_date
options_container
page_layout
price
productinfo
qty_loc1
qty_loc2
qty_loc3
ram_size
required_options
response_time
room
serial_number
shape
short_description
small_image
small_image_label
special_from_date
special_price
special_to_date
status
tax_class_id
thumbnail
thumbnail_label
updated_at
url_key
url_path
visibility
weight
qty
min_qty
use_config_min_qty
is_qty_decimal
backorders
use_config_backorders
min_sale_qty
use_config_min_sale_qty
max_sale_qty
use_config_max_sale_qty
is_in_stock
notify_stock_qty
use_config_notify_stock_qty
manage_stock
use_config_manage_stock
stock_status_changed_auto
use_config_qty_increments
qty_increments
use_config_enable_qty_inc
enable_qty_increments
_links_related_sku
_links_related_position
_links_crosssell_sku
_links_crosssell_position
_links_upsell_sku
_links_upsell_position
_associated_sku
_associated_default_qty
_associated_position
_tier_price_website
_tier_price_customer_group
_tier_price_qty
_tier_price_price
_media_attribute_id
_media_image
_media_lable
_media_position
_media_is_disabled
```

but still no product image.

this my .csv file screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Posting the header line and at least one product line of your import `.csv` file may be helpful to others to help you.

Comment: Please add at least one example product line per file. Otherwise nobody really can try to reproduce your issue, but only guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is the old enemy - nothing new here.

Just put a './' before each and every one of your image entries in your spreadsheet. In that way it should work.

Also try just a slash if './' does not work.

You did not say how you were importing, are you on Magmi?

Comment: If the OP is using the default Magento import OOB, I'd rather recommend to use **no leading slash** at all, since Magento inserts a `DS` itself (`$this->getTmpDir() . DS . $fileName`). See [`Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Uploader::move`](http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.7/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Uploader.php)

Comment: thanks IRIS, I am importing products by this. system>import/export>import

Comment: Not sure if I can help as I am likely to use dataflow, Magmi or a custom script. :-(

Answer (score 0):

When you import from import/export put the images in media/import/ folder and put the relative path in excel sheet /{name of the image}

For example i have uploaded my images in media/import/att/

The excel sheet like this .

```
image   small_image thumbnail
/att/6747.jpg   /att/6747.jpg   /att/6747.jpg
/att/6748.jpg   /att/6748.jpg   /att/6748.jpg
/att/7962.jpg   /att/7962.jpg   /att/7962.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Store Manager by eMagicOne, it is simpler to import with it and there is free trial version. You will just need to put names or URLs of images in csv file and sku for identification. No trouble with column names, etc.

Answer (score 0):

image   small_image thumbnail
/import/6747.jpg   /import/6747.jpg   /import/6747.jpg

insert all images on import folder and assign 0777 permission to to media/import, media/catalog, media/product or media/tmp after that import file and complete clear cache or re indexing, after that check.